# Contact from in codeigniter without using gmail user and password

Tags: codeigniter

I used the following code in controller of my contact form.

```
public function index()
{

    $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'email@mydomain.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'myPassword',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
```

Can i send the email without using "smtp_user" and "smtp_pass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `mail`protocol in the config.
See the docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

You can use the default config and send email like:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```